# JDialog implementing Runnable does not show content

Tags: java, swing, runnable, jdialog

For a Java application I'm trying to create a very simple "loading" dialog for a long operation to do when pressing a button. I did it by opening a thread with the dialog with a gif in it, and closing the dialog and the thread when the function returns.

The dialog opens, but no image or text is shown.

This is the button code:

```
private void botonResolverActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(areaTematicaSeleccionada != ""){
        Cargando c = new Cargando();
        Thread performer = new Thread(c);
        performer.start();
        cpresentacion.resuelveAreaTematica(areaTematicaSeleccionada);
        cpresentacion.actualizaAreaTematicaSeleccionadaGestores(areaTematicaSeleccionada);
        c.dispose();
        try {
            performer.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Ooops");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the loading class, that is inside the other class:

```
private static class Cargando extends javax.swing.JDialog implements Runnable {
    /** Creates new form test */
    public Cargando() {
        super((JDialog)null, true);
        initComponents();
    }

    public void run() {
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/presentacion/loading_small.gif"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel2.setText("Cargando...");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(62, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(54, 54, 54))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 219, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents              

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration 

}
```

But if I put a main on the inner class and run it alone, it works perfectly. Any ideas on either how to show the dialog content, or how to implement a simple "loading" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread performer = new Thread(c);
//...
try {
    performer.join();
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Ooops");
}
```

Say hello to a blocked Event Dispatching Thread.  Basically what this means is the EDT is unable to process new events (including paint request) because it's blocked at the `performer.join` call.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

You have a few basic options.

### You Could...

Use a `SwingWorker` to perform the long running operation and utilise it's `done` method to update the UI when it's done.

This also provides useful methods for syncing updates back to the UI easily, should you need them

Based on your example code, I would pass a reference of the dialog to the `SwingWorker` and override it's `done` method so you can `dispose` of the dialog...

Comment: I finally created the dialog in the main thread and created a SwingWorker that does the long operation in `doInBackground`, with the dialog as a parameter. Then in the main thread I blocked with `dialog.setVisible(true)`. In the SwingWorker, the method `done` disposes the dialog. Thank you for your hints.